# How to compare two averages for the same column?

Tags: tableau-api

I want to take an average of the whole data and then filter that data and take another average and then compare the two. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use LOD expression.  In case you want detailed solution please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Translating on sample superstore-
The following expression will give average of sales for entire data

```
{ Avg([sales])}
```

across all rows.  The following expression will, however, give category wise average sales

```
{FIXED [Category]: avg([sales])}
```

across all rows again.  If you want to apply filters on these calculations add that filter to context but be cautious that the filters will then filter the data used for calculations in both the expressions.  If you just want to filter data for viewing purpose and not the calculations dont add the filters to context.